# Is it possible to add properties of the object to another(new) property

Tags: javascript, arrays

If for some reason I want to combine two of the other properties inside an object, am I able to do this?

For example, if I have:

```
Cars = {
  myFirstCar = { model: "mazda", color: "grey" }
  myCurrentCar = { model: "toyota", color: "black" }
}
```

And say I want to add another property inside of `myFirstCar` that will combine the `model` one, and the `color` one. Something like this:

```
Cars = {
  myFirstCar = { model: "mazda", color: "grey", conclusion: model + color }
  myCurrentCar = { model: "toyota", color: "black" }
}
```

Comment: What is the role of the second ("current") car in your question? Also, this syntax is not javascript which cannot have `=` after property names.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the other syntax errors in your code, no you can't do that exactly like that. Instead you'd do something like this:

```
myFirstCar = { model: "mazda", color: "grey" }
myFirstCar.conclusion = myFirstCar.model + myFirstCar.color;
```

The rest of your code is invalid. I'm not sure what the construct

```
Cars = {
   a = b
   c = d
 }
```

is supposed to achieve. If you're trying to instantiate an object, use `:` instead of `=`. If you want an array, use `[]` instead of `{}` and remove the variables names as well as the assignment `=`.

Comment: what syntax errorS? :o The only one I can notice is the comma in the general object... what else? 0_o  PS: and thanks for your reply, but I know about this approach

Comment: I elaborated on the syntax errors with my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that with the ES6 [computed property name syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get#Using_a_computed_property_name):

```js
var cars = {
  myFirstCar: { model: "mazda", color: "grey", 
                get conclusion() { return this.model + this.color } },
  myCurrentCar: { model: "toyota", color: "black" }
}
console.log(cars.myFirstCar);
// Let's update the color, ... and print it again
cars.myFirstCar.color = 'orange';
console.log(cars.myFirstCar);
```

As you can see in the snippet, this is a *live* property: it follows the updates to the properties.

But if you have multiple car objects, it might be useful to use a constructor for car objects, which defines this extra property:

```js
function Car(model, color) {
    this.model = model;
    this.color = color;
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'conclusion', {
        get: function() { return this.model + this.color; },
        enumerable: true
    });
}

var cars = {
  myFirstCar: new Car("mazda", "grey"),
  myCurrentCar: new Car("toyota", "black")
}
console.log(cars.myFirstCar);
console.log(cars.myCurrentCar);
```